# JavaScript incompatibilities issues with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I am using jQuery as well as twitter bootstrap for my site. I am using a scroll spy, A carousel and an AJAX form submit. I have tested these in three browsers. They work in chrome and FF but not in internet explorer.

Im new to the technologies so I may have missed something important for compatibility
Below are the scripts im using.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/parsley.js"></script>



<!-- script to make the navigation scroll -->
<script>

    var $root = $('html, body');

    $('#nav a').click(function() {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;

    });

</script>

  <script>

          // AJAX submit
          $("#emailForm").submit(function() {

            var url = "email.php"; 

            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: $("#emailForm").serialize(),
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       $('#emailForm')[0].reset();
                       $('#contactForm').prepend('<h1 class="text-success" id="messageSent">Message sent!</h1>');
                       $("#messageSent").fadeIn("slow");
                       window.location.href = '#contact';
                   }
                 });

            return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });

</script>

<!-- script to make the carousel work  -->
<script>

      // carousel demo
      $('#myCarousel').carousel();

</script>
```

Could someone possibly point out/ explain the errors of my ways

EDIT: I am using IE 8 to test this in.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you add them to your question?

Comment: Which version of `IE` are you referring to?

Comment: I have checked the console in chrome and there is no error/output. 
I have not checked in IE. Could you possible explain how to do it in IE as im not aware of how to do it

Comment: @phpNoOb I have added to question I am testing in IE8

Comment: Try combining the three `<script></script>` into one `<script type="text/javascript">--your code here --</script>`

Comment: What actually is the problem behaviour in IE? You mention three separate functions - are they all broken? Please describe expected behaviour and actual behaviour...

Comment: Unless my memory is working against me - In IE, you can't print to the console unless it's already open. Yeah, I know - smart huh? :sarcasm:

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes all the function do nothing in IE there is no behaviour to report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

You are using version 2.0.0 of jQuery, which won't work in IE 8. You can read about this [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/).

I suggest you use a version of jQuery that's compatible with the lower IE versions, for example 1.9.1:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: YES! Thank you very much my friend. I though my code logic was floored somewhere. saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: _"for example 1.8.2"_ - Or 1.9.1, given that it's the latest that's compatible with older browsers. Although it did introduce quite a few changes.